# chrome extension message from background.js to content.js with response, TypeError cannot read property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello I am new to chrome extensions and I'm trying to make a extension. I want the background.js to send a request to content.js every time the user goes to another tab and for that I have this code inside background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "update"}, function(response) {
          console.log(response.proto);
      });
    });
});
```

and in content.js I have this code to receive the request and send a response:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request.greeting);
        var protocol = window.location.protocol;
        sendResponse({ proto: protocol });
    }
);
```

I get this error in the background console:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'proto' of undefined
    at background.js:6:32
```

and I get no error in the normal console. I have used this documentation:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

and

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content.js` only runs in tabs whose `url` defined in the `manifest.json` file. if the `url` of the active tab  does not match these urls ,the `background.js` gets none.

Comment: I have this in my manifest.json file: `"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],`

Comment: try to refresh old tabs to load content.js after you modify your chrome extensions@Linus